keda-operator fails authentication with the AWS IRSA role
We are setting up Keda which scales up a deployment on the basis of SQS Queue length. The deployment that we are trying to deploy (let's say app-1) already has a service-account attached which has the "eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn": {role-arn} annotation and SQS access for the pod is working properly.
Is there any way for Keda to use the permissions already granted to the app-1 pods?
I don't want to annotate the keda-operator service account with the eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn annotation because in that scenario I would have to create a separate service account for keda-operator because it will cater the autoscaling needs for multiple deployments(each having different set of permissions).
I would appreciate any help. Thanks.
I have already tried adding "YOUR_OIDC:sub": "system:serviceaccount:keda:keda-operator" in app-1's IRSA policy trust definition, and set the provider: aws in the TriggerAuthentication, but it is still giving 403 Access Denied.
